# library error after compiling

Tags: matlab, deployment, compilation

Using 2012b on Centos6 I compiled my code using deploytool.

To be sure I'm doing things correctly, I re-install the MCR to make sure I'm using the exact version matlab wants me to use.    Following the instructions after installing the MCR (v83) I append the corresponding paths to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and XAPPLRESDIR.

When I use the run_myProgram.sh script. It echos out the library paths and I can see that the MCR paths are correct.

However, at the startup of my compiled program, I'm getting this error:
"error while loading shared libraries: libmwmclmcrrt.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Anyone out there have a way to fix this?   For example, is it a problem with my system configuration or a problem with my deployment?

The plot thickens.  I noticed that in the MCR installation, I only have libmwmclmcrrt.so.8.3.   How does the deploytool not give me the version I need?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download MCR version 8.0 for r2012b. Please see the table here : [MCR Version Table](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102061-what-is-the-version-of-the-matlab-compiler-runtime-mcr-that-corresponds-to-the-version-of-matlab-c)